# How to save Heart click count in localStorage like instagram?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I used some codes from google but the problem is when user **click on heart** it just animate but not able to count the value and not able to store the value in localstorage. I want to store the click count value in localstorage so that if user click on heart it will save the value in his browser after refreshing also his clicked value should be saved in his browser until an unless he retained the clicked value to remove the heart.

I am new in this please help me.

Below is the code

**Jquery 3.5.1**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="heart"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.heart {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: url(http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/4545/XdJDuY.png) no-repeat;  
  cursor: pointer;
  
}
.heart-blast {
  background-position: -2800px 0;
  transition: background 1s steps(28);
}
```

**Script**

```
$(function() {
 
  $(".heart").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("heart-blast");
  });
});
```

Comment: at least try to attempt your need. you can follow https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: You haven't written any code that will save and restore it. It doesn't happen by itself.

Answer (score 1):

first add a counter variable

```
let count;
```

then increase it by 1 in every click

```
$(function() {
 
  $(".heart").on("click", function() {
count+=1;
    $(this).toggleClass("heart-blast"); 
  });
});
```

then save the variable to `localStorage`

```
$(function() {
 
  $(".heart").on("click", function() {
count+=1;
    $(this).toggleClass("heart-blast"); 
  localStorage.setItem(count,"heartClicks");
  });
});
```

to get the variable again from local storage use `localStorage.GetItem`

```
let clicks = localStorage.getItem("heartClicks");
```